# Embeded vlc media player not playing in Internet explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, media-player

I have embedded vlc media player for my asp.net website using the below code:

```
< embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"                                                  runat="server" ID="video" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" height="480" > 
< /embed >



protected void button_play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Videos/Question" + lblQuestionCode.Text + ".mp4");

    video.Attributes.Add("AutoStart", "true");

    video.Attributes.Add("target", "file:///" + path);
}
```

It works fine with Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox,but does not run on internet explorer.
Can anyone suggest what should be done?

Comment: which version of IE you are using? IE8 or lesser version does not support HTML5 and that's why I think problem is there